# How do I get Google Chrome on (Android) work with JQM? I can't make the Google Chrome (Mobile) browser scroll down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

Basically I developed a webapp using Jquery Mobile and am having problems when looking at this web app on google chrome on my Android phone. For some reason I can click buttons but when I go to a page that has to be scrolled down to see data, the google chrome browser refuses to scroll. However, when I test this app on Firefox i do not have this problem, Anybody have any ideas?? Anything would be greatly appreciated!

The link to my web app is http://testgroundwebapp.appspot.com

Comment: Hi, could you add more information about the web app? Maybe some code or some test site we could see? You can use jsfiddle.net to set some example too.

Comment: Is there any code or special styling relating to the scrollable sections you can post? I don't know anything about this, but I'm thinking it might help others who do identify the incompatibility (unless its blatantly obvious).

Comment: The Link to my web app is http://testgroundwebapp.appspot.com, when the index page shows you can just click enter and see the web app

Comment: FOUND A Workaround to this problem by checking out asyrafs version of jquery splitview, He uses a CSS file and in his css file he has one command called 
  .splitview .ui-content {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    z-index:1;
  }
I figured out if you call this in the div tag you want to adjust to scroll it will actually work in google chrome

Comment: Did you ever find a proper solution to this? Can you expand a little bit on your latest comment?